# Access content-length in custom WCF MessageEncoder

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

I am attempting to show the progress of a streamed WCF message by implementing a custom MessageEncoder and overriding the ReadMessage method. I can download the data and report progress as it is coming in but I am interested to know the full message size before this happens.

Is it possible in the encoder or somewhere else to see the size of the incoming message before it is actually downloaded? I know the length is available in the HTTP headers but I don't see a way to access them.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public override Message ReadMessage(Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)
{
    MemoryStream content = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    var bytesRead = 0;

    do
    {
        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        content.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        // Report progress
        this.ReportProgress("Downloading...", bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead > 0);
```

Comment: You could try stream.Length. This will throw if it's not implemented but it might be and might give you what you want. If it doesn't the only thing I can think of is manipulating the incoming stream to tack the length on at the very beginning - that's a tad hacky though and requires that you have the ability to manipulate the source of the stream.

Comment: stream.Length does work if the entire message comes back buffered. In this case (streamed) though the Length will throw an exception.